# Files not accepted by SkyDrive

Tags: onedrive

Which file types will not upload and open in Microsoft's SkyDrive?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there any restriction of the type of files you can upload but you can only [edit or create Office files in the browser.](http://explore.live.com/office-web-apps)

Answer (score 1):

Each file is limited to 50 MB in size, or it will not upload.  Check your file size...

Answer (score 1):

They will accept any type of file. On my SkyDrive account I have MP4 files, ZIPs, RARs, Tar.gz's and all kind of archive, but it's for upload, for editing, just Office files and plain text. But the files needs to be -50MB in size.

*PS: I've stored all my podcast media there and I had no problem*